# Can someone explains the exact behavior of RabbitMQ Channel? and also if executing channel.basicAck closes the channel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to execute a queue read operation on a RabbitMQ Queue by using `channel.basicConsume()` method. The queue contains more than one message an when i am trying to acknowledge each message one by one, after acknowledging each message in queue the channel is being closed by `channel.basicAck()` method. Is this the expected behavior of the channel?

to read more than one messages from the queue i am using the following code. i 
have overridden the `handelDelivery()` method of `Consumer` class.

```
ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
Connection connection = connFactory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.queueDeclare("sampleQueue", true, false, false, null);
channel.basicQos(1);

Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(){
@Override
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelopeenvelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(message);
            channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
            }

    };

 boolean autoAck = true;
 channel.basicConsume(queueName,autoAck,consumer);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `autoAck` to `true`, which means your message consumption is automatically acknowledged.

because of this, the call to `basickAck` is throwing an exception saying there is no delivery tag to ack (or it has already been ack'd).

when a channel throws an exception, it closes.

to fix this and get the expected behavior, change this line:

`boolean autoAck = true;`

to this:

`boolean autoAck = false;`

Comment: hi Derick,  when i change the value `boolean autoAck = false` the call to the queue is returning me only one message and clearing the queue.